# Справочник по DTD

Tags: xml, книги, парсер

Посоветуйте какой-нибудь справочник по DTD с примерами, а то надо написать, по XML файлу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не поверите, но на Википедии есть [достаточно подробная статья](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Definition).

Кроме того:

- [DTD Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/default.asp)
- [DTD в примерах](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/DTDTutorial/General_rus/book.html)

Comment: вы не поверите, но я ее читал. Подробно, но недостаточно.